# How to start the shell in MinGW-64?

Tags: linux, windows-10

I just downloaded the last version of MinGW-64 (the install file is named "win-builds-1.5.0").

I've installed it, it is installing some 92 packages, and now when I go to the folder "C:\Programs\MinGW-64\bin", I can't find any "bash.exe" or "sh.exe"

The installer didn't ask me if I want to install extra packages. I also noticed the "bin" folder has wget but there is no cat, grep, head, tail, wc, tr, sort, uniq etc.

How can I start a shell?

(I am using Windows 10 x64)

Comment: I just noticed that the shell is included in the MSYS2, not in the MinGW package. therefore it might be good to close/remove this question. Or to leave it for those who might make the same confusion that I did.

Comment: You can post that solution as an answer. It will help people who have the same question in the future.

Answer (score 6):

Well, this is embarrassing but I noticed that the shell and the basic utilities are included in the MSYS2, not in the MinGW package, and that is clearly stated in the project description.

Well.. maybe others will make the same confusion and then my confused question and then at least this answer might be useful.

Comment: You are correct.  I got the shell as a side effect of installing Git, so I know nothing about the install or where the shell comes from. And so I found this.

Answer (score 1):

So to fill out @BearCode's answer to his own question with a specific command to use, one way is to run `bash` from within `cmd`.